# HttpWebRequest to Dropbox from Silverlight application

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, httpwebrequest, dropbox

I am following [this article](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-token) to connect to Dropbox datastores , 
I first tried to send the post request (mentioned in that article) from WPF application using the following code (everything was fine and I got the response I expected which is the access token )

But when I moved that code to a siverlight application , first it was compiled correctly but I got an exception at runtime and I don`t know why

I have been trying to solve that exception for three days now , but I can't get it solved. So I really appreciate your help

Code:

```
// You can obtain a real authorization code to experiment with here 
// https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=2n01eqvmuh6mzah&response_type=code

string code = "mQ6_l6tky1gAAAAAAAAAAQ6izgHBSZV3m93DwKDmdQA";  // it is a single use (I`ve used it)

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/token");   // Base URI
sb.Append("?code=" + code);                            // First parameter
sb.Append("&grant_type=authorization_code");
sb.Append("&client_id=2n01eqvmuh6mzah");
sb.Append("&client_secret=2xiphn1c9ivsktu");

HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(sb.ToString()));
myHttpWebRequest1.Method = "POST";

myHttpWebRequest1.BeginGetResponse((result) =>
{
    var response = ((HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(result);

    // here where i get the exception: 
    //An exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in System.Windows.dll but was not handled in user code
    // details below

    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}, myHttpWebRequest1);
```

Exception details :

```
  System.Security.SecurityException was unhandled by user code
  Message=""
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
       at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at SilverlightApplication2.MainPage.<.ctor>b__0(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass19.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__17(Object state2)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
  InnerException: System.Security.SecurityException
       Message=Security error.
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
            at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to make cross-domain HTTP requests in Silverlight requires a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` or `crossdomain.xml` file to be served from the root of the target domain. Dropbox doesn't serve such a file.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any idea how to change localhost server provided by visual studio to emulate my final deployment server instead?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What do you want to do on localhost?

Comment: when i launch SilverLight app while development its url looks like this http://localhost:9922/silverlightApplication.aspx . i want to change that address so when i launch it from visual studio i get my real deployment server instead. for example http://dropbox.com/silverlightApplication.aspx  to avoid cross-domain issue

Comment: You're going to deploy this app onto a Dropbox domain? It still won't work, since you can presumably only run the app on `www.dropbox.com` (perhaps in a public folder?), and the API is on `api.dropbox.com`, `api-content.dropbox.com`, and `api-notify.dropbox.com`. Since those aren't the same domain as `www.dropbox.com`, you'll still see the same cross-domain issue.